# php - regular expression matching first occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I require to match first occurrence of the following pattern starting with `\s` or `(` then `NIC` followed by any characters followed `#` or `.` followed by `5` or `6` digits.

Regular expression used :

```
preg_match('/[\\s|(]NIC.*[#|.]\d{5,6}/i', trim($test), $matches1);
```

Example:

1. `$test = "(NIC.123456";`  //  works correctly
2. `$test = "(NIC.123456 oldnic#65703 checking"`   // produce result `(NIC.123456 oldnic#65703`

But it needs to be only `(NIC.123456`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `?` quantifier for a non-greedy match. Here `.*` is matching the most amount possible.

You also don't need to double escape `\\s` here, you can just use `\s` and you can just combine the selective characters inside your character class instead of adding in the pipe `|` delimiter.

Also note that your expression will match strings like the following `(NIC_CCC.123456`,  to avoid this you can use a word boundary `\b` matching the boundary between a word character and not a word character.

```
preg_match('/(?<=^|\s)\(nic\b.*?[#.]\d{5,6}/i', $test, $match);
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<=           look behind to see if there is:
 ^             the beginning of the string
  |            OR
 \s            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
)              end of look-behind
\(             '('
 nic           'nic'
 \b            the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
 .*?           any character except \n (0 or more times)
  [#.]         any character of: '#', '.'
  \d{5,6}      digits (0-9) (between 5 and 6 times)
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/yD9cO3)

Answer (score 1):

have tried using
    $test1 = explode(" ", $test); 
and use $test1[0] to display your result.